# Quais parâmetros usar no mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php

Olá, eu não sei quais parâmetros(só sei um deles) usar no mysql_fetch_array, por favor me digam qual é e como conseguir ele.

```
    include "conection.php";

session_start(0);

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$login = $_SESSION['login_usuario'];

$sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login'");

while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql, $sql))
{
    $nome = $linha['nome'];
    $email = $linha['email'];
    $idade = $linha['idade'];
    $cidade = $linha['cidade'];
}
```

Grato desde já.

Comment: Já olhou a documentação? [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php). Evite usar funções `mysql_*`.

Comment: Sim, já li, mas não entendi :c

Comment: O que exatamente você não entendeu?

Comment: "O tipo de array que deve ser obtida. é uma constante e pode ter os seguintes valores: MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_NUM, e o valor padrão de MYSQL_BOTH." isso

Comment: Eu só queria saber oque exatamente devo colocar no segundo parametro do mysql_fetch_array.

Comment: Postei uma resposta, se tiver dúvidas, avise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Eu só queria saber oque exatamente devo colocar no segundo parametro
>   do mysql_fetch_array.

O segundo argumento é opcional, indica que tipo de *array* deve ser retornada.

Os valores possíveis são: `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, `MYSQLI_NUM`, ou `MYSQLI_BOTH`.

Por padrão, a função [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) irá assumir `MYSQLI_BOTH` para este parâmetro.

- `MYSQLI_ASSOC`: Retorna um *array* associativa.
- `MYSQLI_NUM`: Retorna um *array* com índice numérico.
- `MYSQLI_BOTH`:  Retorna um *array* com ambos os índices, numérico e [associativo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vetor_associativo) ([multidimensional](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp)).

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda mano.

Comment: @LucasCarezia Disponha =). Não se esqueça de trocar `mysql_fetch_array` por **`mysqli_fetch_array()`**. Se possível, marque a resposta clicando no ✔ abaixo dos votos.